# odoo.http: Exception during request handling

Tags: ubuntu, pycharm, odoo, odoo-16

When I'm trying to run Odoo16 in my PyCharm I get the following error and don't know what's the problem:

```
2023-05-13 13:21:03,574 31759 ERROR dbodoo16 odoo.http: Exception during request handling. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/avril/PycharmProjects/odoo-16/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1987, in __call__
    response = request._serve_db()
  File "/home/avril/PycharmProjects/odoo-16/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1583, in _serve_db
    return service_model.retrying(self._serve_ir_http, self.env)
  File "/home/avril/PycharmProjects/odoo-16/odoo/odoo/service/model.py", line 134, in retrying
    result = func()
  File "/home/avril/PycharmProjects/odoo-16/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1611, in _serve_ir_http
    ir_http._post_dispatch(response)
  File "/home/avril/PycharmProjects/odoo-16/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line 161, in _post_dispatch
    request.dispatcher.post_dispatch(response)
  File "/home/avril/PycharmProjects/odoo-16/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1679, in post_dispatch
    self.request._save_session()
  File "/home/avril/PycharmProjects/odoo-16/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1511, in _save_session
    self.future_response.set_cookie('session_id', sess.sid, max_age=SESSION_LIFETIME, httponly=True)
  File "/home/avril/PycharmProjects/odoo-16/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1125, in set_cookie
    werkzeug.Response.set_cookie(self, key, value=value, max_age=max_age, expires=expires, path=path, domain=domain, secure=secure, httponly=httponly, samesite=samesite)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/werkzeug/sansio/response.py", line 258, in set_cookie
    charset = self._charset if self._charset != "utf-8" else None
AttributeError: 'FutureResponse' object has no attribute '_charset'
2023-05-13 13:21:03,575 31759 INFO dbodoo16 werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [13/May/2023 13:21:03] "GET /web/database/manager HTTP/1.1" 500 - 8 0.002 0.245
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29661764/10794031) will help. You don't explain how you configured the PyCharm IDE and how you are running it, please edit the question to include additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a newer version of `werkzeug` so the solution is to uninstall the current version and install the recommended version for Odoo 16 and python 3.8 (0.16.1)

**Uninstall werkzeug**

```
sudo pip3 uninstall werkzeug
```

**Install werkzeug == 0.16.1**

```
sudo pip3 install werkzeug Werkzeug==0.16.1
```